# More Adsense in middle of Blogger post

Tags: blogger, adsense

I'm trying to add more Adsense ads in the middle of a Blogger post.

This is basically the code you can find everywhere on the web for one ad:

```html
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle1" + data:post.id'></div> 
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'> 
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0"> 
<!-- Add here the code of your ad -->
</div> </b:if> </b:if> 
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle2" + data:post.id'> 
<data:post.body/> </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var obj0=document.getElementById("adsmiddle1<data:post.id/>"); 
var obj1=document.getElementById("adsmiddle2<data:post.id/>"); 
var s=obj1.innerHTML; var r=s.search(/\x3C!-- adsense --\x3E/igm); 
if(r>0) {obj0.innerHTML=s.substr(0,r);obj1.innerHTML=s.substr(r+16);} </script>
```

It works perfectly with the parsed code of my Ad. The Ad appears where I put `<!-- adsense -->`. The point is that I want to add MORE Ads, thanks to this script. I would like a new Ad to appear where I put another trigger word like `<!-- adsense2 -->`. How should I edit it?

Comment: @edubriguenti Your edit did not improve this post in any way at all. Please do not make any more edits like that.

Comment: I do not agree since readability is an improvement. Anyway, I understand your concern.

Answer (score 1):

As per the logic, 2 sections are needed to split and put the Adsense code in betweeen. To show 2 ads, you will have to divide in 3 sections.

**Note:-** It's not an actual answer but this is how it can be done. I have tweaked this code to push 2 ads at 33% and 66% of total length of my blog post and it works.

Here's a sample code

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div expr:id='&quot;aim1&quot; + data:post.id'/>   
<!-- Your Ad Code -->  
<div expr:id='&quot;aim2&quot; + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>
</div>
<!-- Your Ad Code -->   
<div expr:id='&quot;aim3&quot; + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var obj0 = document.getElementById(&quot;aim1<data:post.id/>&quot;);
var obj1 = document.getElementById(&quot;aim2<data:post.id/>&quot;);
var obj2 = document.getElementById(&quot;aim3<data:post.id/>&quot;);

// Make changes in your logic to find the words like adsense2 and find substring

</script>

</b:if>
```

You will have to search new word and also consider length of the new world. The length of word  `<!-- adsense2 -->` would be 17 so you will have to use `s.substr(r+17)`